# Line-oriented streams in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, stream, buffer

I'm developing a multi-process application using Node.js. In this application, a parent process will spawn a child process and communicate with it using a JSON-based messaging protocol over a pipe. I've found that large JSON messages may get "cut off", such that a single "chunk" emitted to the data listener on the pipe does not contain the full JSON message. Furthermore, small JSON messages may be grouped in the same chunk. Each JSON message will be delimited by a newline character, and so I'm wondering if there is already a utility that will buffer the pipe read stream such that it emits one line at a time (and hence, for my application, one JSON document at a time). This seems like it would be a pretty common use case, so I'm wondering if it has already been done.

I'd appreciate any guidance anyone can offer. Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about just using good old HTTP?  Why are you inventing a new IPC protocol? Sending JSON messages over HTTP is a solved problem, and node is great at HTTP.

Comment: Could you describe how you would do it with HTTP? Right now, I don't see how this would change the nature of the problem, as I believe you would still be reading chunks from a stream.

Comment: You code your child process as a regular node.js HTTP server.  The ability to accept and send JSON messages is provided by the express.js/connect.js bodyParser middleware. https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js.  This handles the chunks in the standard node.js event driven way.  No need to re-invent this mechanism.

Comment: Also check out axon https://github.com/visionmedia/axon. Set the encoding of each socket to JSON and then you can easily send and receive JSON objects

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Pedro's [carrier](https://github.com/pgte/carrier) can help you?

> Carrier helps you implement new-line
>   terminated protocols over node.js.
>
> The client can send you chunks of
>   lines and carrier will only notify you
>   on each completed line.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this problem is to send JSON messages each terminated with some special unicode character. A character that you would never normally get in the JSON string. Call it TERM.

So the sender just does "JSON.stringify(message) + TERM;" and writes it.
The reciever then splits incomming data on the TERM and parses the parts with JSON.parse() which is pretty quick.
The trick is that the last message may not parse, so we simply save that fragment and add it to the beginning of the next message when it comes. Recieving code goes like this:

```
        s.on("data", function (data) {
        var info = data.toString().split(TERM);
        info[0] = fragment + info[0];
        fragment = '';

        for ( var index = 0; index < info.length; index++) {
            if (info[index]) {
                try {
                    var message = JSON.parse(info[index]);
                    self.emit('message', message);
                } catch (error) {
                    fragment = info[index];
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Where "fragment" is defined somwhere where it will persist between data chunks.

But what is TERM? I have used the unicode replacement character '\uFFFD'. One could also use the technique used by twitter where messages are separated by '\r\n' and tweets use '\n' for new lines and never contain '\r\n'

I find this to be a lot simpler than messing with including lengths and such like.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to send length of json data before each message as fixed-length prefix (4 bytes?) and have a simple un-framing parser which buffers small chunks or splits bigger ones.

You can try [node-binary](https://github.com/substack/node-binary) to avoid writing parser manually. Look at `scan(key, buffer)` documentation example - it does exactly line-by line reading.

Answer (score 1):

As long as newlines (or whatever delimiter you use) will only delimit the JSON messages and not be embedded in them, you can use the following pattern:

```
let buf = ''
s.on('data', data => {
  buf += data.toString()
  const idx = buf.indexOf('\n')
  if (idx < 0) { return } // No '\n', no full message
  let lines = buf.split('\n')
  buf = lines.pop() // if ends in '\n' then buf will be empty
  for (let line of lines) {
    // Handle the line
  }
})
```

Comment: You'll want to change `const buf = ''` to `let buf = ''` in order for this to work; can't assign to a constant variable.

Comment: @user1974458 true. Fixed.