# Is possible to read independently every stdout flushed string form a Child Process in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Cstdout:%d ", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cstderr:%d ", i);
        fflush(stderr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is: *Cstdout:0 Cstderr:0 Cstdout:1 Cstderr:1 Cstdout:2 Cstderr:2*

And i want to process its output with a node.js script like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('./io');

var Jstdout = 0, Jstderr = 0;

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Jstdout:' + Jstdout + ' ' + data);
  ++Jstdout;
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Jstderr:' + Jstderr + ' ' + data);
  ++Jstderr;
});

ls.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

The output of this script is:

*Jstdout:0 Cstdout:0 Cstdout:1 Cstdout:*

*Jstderr:0 Cstderr:0 Cstderr:1 Cstderr:2*

*child process exited with code 0*

But i want something like:

*Jstdout:0 Cstdout:0*

*Jstderr:0 Cstderr:0*

*Jstdout:1 Cstdout:1*

*Jstderr:1 Cstderr:1*

*Jstdout:2 Cstdout:2*

*Jstderr:2 Cstderr:2*

*child process exited with code 0*

---

I guess your C++ program is filling the buffers faster than your node.js can read it. What happens if you let your child process wait about 100ms after each iteration? –  Dirk Horsten

What Dirk Horsten is true:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Cstdout:%d ", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep (1);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cstderr:%d ", i);
        fflush(stderr);
        sleep (1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code will produce the output that i want but i want to format the outputs of programs that i haven't write, and i can't easy put delays in those programs.

For example i want to color the output of valgrind but the output of valgrind uses stdout and stderr simultaneously. When i try to do that the position of the blocks of text gets changed.

In the next script i trying to color the output to the program blue and the output of valgrind red:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('valgrind', [process.argv[2]]);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('\033[1;34m' + data + '\033[0m');
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('\033[1;31m' + data + '\033[0m');
});

ls.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: I guess your C++ program is filling the buffers faster than your node.js can read it. What happens if you let your child process wait about 100ms after each iteration?

Comment: That program is only an example.
I want to do this because i want to color the output of valgrind using a node.js script.

And yes if i put a delay after the flush it will work as i wish, but i can't do that to valgrind.

Comment: `ls.stdout` is a [Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) that inherently has no capability to distinguish between one `fflush` from another. It's all just a constant stream of data to it. You'll probably have to read the `data` yourself to distinguish out what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, at least using conventional means.

Child process output is received via pipes. Pipe is an object provided by OS. Internally it has a buffer; every write() on a pipe appends to the buffer. The boundaries of individual chunks are not preserved — if the writer is fast enough it will manage to queue multiple items before the reader has a chance to read anything. The reader will receive any data currently available; if multiple chunks were buffered it MAY receive them all at once.

Surely this issue make exchanging messages via pipes a bit harder; to make it possible to split concatenated messages there must be some indication where the message ends (Ex: a newline terminates a message [[some nodejs context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573774/line-oriented-streams-in-node-js)]).

A note about flush. In C FILE object has a buffer of its own. Flush transfers buffer contents into the underlying OS object, i.e. flush translates into write on a pipe.

Comment: Conclusion: monthy_programmer will have to find a separator or in the output from his child_process (i.e. valgrind)

Comment: Oh and it would be necessary to use the same pipe for stdin and stderr since messages sent to different pipes arrive completely out of sync. I wonder if it is possible with nodejs?